# Undo rewrite domain's name using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns

So this is my problem, actually I just made an unintentional eror with my domain. FYI, my old domain is `alfathmulia.com` or I can access it with `https://alfathmulia.com/` before. But then, I wrote this down in my .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost/mydomain/build/ \[L,R=301\]`

And the result is I can't access my old domain. If I'm trying to access it, that always redirecting into `http://localhost/mydomain/build/`.

But then, I've tried to undo this line in my .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost/mydomain/build/ \[L,R=301\]`

also remake .htaccess file same as before I write this line

`RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost/mydomain/build/ \[L,R=301\]`

but it didn't changed anything. So, how can I get my old domain back and also can access it without being directed to other page or unknown address?

Comment: Redirects with a 301 status code tend to get _cached_ by browsers really strongly, so you will likely simply have to delete your recent browsing history.

Comment: @CBroe Aight, thank you!